# Apache ServerAlias not redirecting to correct ServerName

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

i'm try to setup multiple wordpress sites on my Amazon EC2 instance. Here's how my httpd.conf file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.domain1.com
   ServerAlias domain1.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.domain2.co
   ServerAlias domain2.co
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2
</VirtualHost>
```

So, when i entered domain1.com or www.domain1.com in the browser, it redirects correctly to the content i wanted and so does www.domain2.co . However, when i entered domain2.co, it doesn't directs to the ServerName www.domain2.co but to the first VirtualHost settings www.domain1.com.

Anything i'm missing out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out guys, the browser caches previous data when domain2.co points to domain1.com. So even when i have set the virtualhost correctly for domain2.co, the browser will still load the previous cached data from domain1.com.

Solution will be to clear browser data.

Found out that another factor affecting this could be because of your ISP.

Read more here: https://sg.godaddy.com/help/what-factors-affect-dns-propagation-time-1746

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Apache will default to the 1st virtual host if it doesn't find a virtualhost match which means your second VirtualHost is being ignored. We use www. as an alias and the domain as the server name.  See if this helps.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain1.com
   ServerAlias www.domain1.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain2.com
   ServerAlias www.domain2.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hey mate, just tried this and same thing, www.domain2.co works but domain2.co directs to the first settings.

Comment: I just noticed that you have .co and not .com in the virtual host definitions .. was that intentional?

Comment: ... Because that would definitely cause the problem you're describing.

Comment: .co is the extension for the 2nd domain.

Comment: This may sound strange, but I've seen uncommon domain extensions like ".co" or ".us" not get handled improperly by DNS.  It could be your Apache server is unable to resolve the .co domains.  If it cannot resolve them, it would do what you're describing.

Comment: Okay, i just added a third domain with a .com extension and still same problem. Could it be there are some settings messing with this?

Comment: This may not be the issue, but in all of my Apache configs, I have quotes around the documentroot.  I would have expected an error, but it could be the issue.  Also, are  your virtualhost definitions in a separate apache config file like httpd-vhosts.conf?  If so, are you "including" the file in your httpd.conf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102430/discussion-between-michael-howe-and-luvnjesus).